# What's the deal with dontEscape support in Uri? .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, http, encoding, uri, httprequest

Documentation state that [dontEscape is deprecated and always false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zh9wcb3.aspx).

However it actually works. Is it a good idea to use it anyway, or is there any other alternative to send non RFC compliant Http requests?

**Sample Code:**

```
Dim U As New Uri("http://www.google.com/>", True)
Dim W As New Net.WebClient()
WL(W.DownloadString(U))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The method has been deprecated. Please use GetComponents() or static UnescapeDataString() to unescape a Uri component or a string. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202"

Citation from obsolete attribute. Have you tried this approaches?

Comment: That's just for reading though, they won't change what HttpRequest sends.

Comment: Can you show some code, cos I've tried to write a sample application and get correct encoding.

Comment: Added sample code, run it use a proxy/sniffer to see what it sends

Comment: Wow actually it did sent it :D Lol I'll just rephrase the question.

Comment: I've just tried and can't found other way :(, it's also interesting to know original task. I mean why you need to send non RFC compliant requests?